# How can I use vectors to achieve the same as this

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

After a good deal of work, I have developed the following code in Python to plot a vector [In this case (2,2,2)] so that it points in the way you would expect from the origin.
It took me some time to gather what the three rotation parameters meant in terms of roll, pitch and yaw. You may need to set Euler XYZ.

I have used a long thin cylinder to be my vector, which suits my purpose and fits with my thin experience of blender. This code plots a vector with an Arrow on it (a cone) half way along and suits my purpose quite well but is somewhat of a bodge.
I works for most vectors but fails when x<0 and y>0 and z>0

```
import bpy
import math
from math import *
x=-5  
y=-10
z=12
yParameter=-1.0
if y < 0:
    if x < 0: 
        yParameter = 1.0
#print ("y para is ",yParameter
for i in range (0,1):

    length=sqrt(z*z+y*y+x*x)


#Create a vector at correct orientation at the origin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=16, radius=0.04, depth=length, end_fill_type='NGON', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0,0,0),rotation=(-acos(z/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)),0,yParameter*acos(y/sqrt(x*x+y*y))))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(x/2, y/2, z/2))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=32, radius1=0.1, radius2=0, depth=0.4, end_fill_type='NGON', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0,0,0), rotation=(-acos(z/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)),0,yParameter*acos(y/sqrt(x*x+y*y))))
```

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(x/2, y/2, z/2))

I feel certain that the huge API in vectors and matrix manipulation should make this job easier but I am struggling with finding how to do it other than with this self-developed cartesian work.

Can any one point me to an understandable code snippet or maybe a tutorial on how to manipulate vectors (in the mathematical sense) within blender python

I find that the blender API is pretty clear on the names of parameters and how to code them but I can find little or nothing on what the parameters actually mean.

Comment: Semicolons are not needed at the end of the line in Python.

Comment: Well I guess that betrays my background so far as programming is concerned but having taken them out, the question remains the same.

Comment: look at [`mathutils`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_64_release/mathutils.html#module-mathutils)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create you a cylinder with (0,0,0) as one end and (x,y,z) as the other:

```
def createVectorLikeThing(x,y,z):
    v = Vector((x,y,z))
    up = Vector((0,0,1))
    if v!=-up:
        rot = up.rotation_difference(v)
    else:
        rot = Quaternion((1,0,0),pi)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=16, radius=0.01, depth=v.length, end_fill_type='NGON', view_align=False, enter_editmode=True)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,0,v.length/2))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=(rot.angle,), axis=rot.axis)
```

The code works with blender 2.63 but **not** with 2.65.

For 2.65 change the last line to:

```
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=rot.angle, axis=rot.axis)
```

Comment: Slight Problem, it does not work, createVector (2,2,2) created a straight vertical cylinder.
I am working on it, at least I can use the api now `i have seen an example.

Comment: 2.65a OSX Mountain Lion. I will ck with Linux. BTW, I have change my code above and it now deals with the case I had issues with but I should be using Mathutils

Comment: perhaps I am using the code wrong, would you mind commenting it a bit? Do I have to change the 0,0,1 ?

Comment: doesn't work on 2.65 linux fedora core 18 either. Just gets a vertical cylinder from the origin

Comment: Example [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/19621). Try pushing "Run Script" a few times.

Comment: Well, some progress, on linux FC18 running on an i3 it works. On the Mac, i get TypeError:Converting py args to operator properties: TRANFORM_OT_rotate.value expected a float type, not tuple

Comment: I will mark as solved but would like to track down python issue